# Can't add more than 105 simple products to bundle product

Tags: products-management, bundle

A weird thing is happening: when I try to save my bundle product with 200 simple products, for example, it limits the simple products quantity to 105. The number 105 does not matter. The thing is why is this happening?

I made some research on Google and could not find anything except that this problem is due to server configuration. But I do not think so... can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is the product complete for everything else?

Answer (score 3):

Try increase your php `max_input_vars` value

See [How to increase maximum POST variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...
It didn't work =/
Any more ideas?

Comment: Hey, man... actually it did work!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Suhosin can also be a culprit when it comes to input restrictions.